# How to get update to check Feature Server

Tags: 7, updating, .info

I have a custom module hosted on a [feature server](https://drupal.org/project/fserver). When I update Drupal how can I get it to check the Feature Server to see if there is an update there?

In the back of my head I thought it was something you could add to *.info*. However I can't find an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `project status url`, which is a property that can be used in your [module's .info file](https://drupal.org/node/542202):

> Allows module maintainers to define a URL to check for updates to their module using the Update status module. No module released on drupal.org should define this parameter. URL should point to an XML feed that accepts requests in the form of http://my.domain.com/projects/{project}/{core}. In that example, project status url should be set to http://my.domain.com/projects.

Comment: Looks the correct way to do it. fserver does not seem to be working but that will be another issue.